# Why qsort in c++ not implemented through template

Tags: c++, generics

If we see qsort signature in stl

```
void qSort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
        int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

1) Why it is not implemented with template, something like

```
    template <typename T, typename Ob>
void qSort(T *base, size_t num, size_t size,
               bool (*compar) (const TOb& left,const TOb& right) )
```

2) Is there any advantage/ disadvantage of each approach.

3) How basically generic function are implemented in industry level code using C++?

Comment: qsort comes from c. Templates are a feature of c++

Comment: Easy enough to implement on your own: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Answer (score 6):

`qsort` comes from C where there are no templates.  If you want a generic sort in C++ use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)